# follow all p tags unless and stop if some other type of sibling appears

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to follow `<p>` tag unless any other type of sibling appears

**Case 1:**

```
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<h3>Foo</h3>
<p>c</p>
```

**Case 2:**

```
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<h2>Foo</h2>
<p>c</p>
```

My code works with the above condition where it follows until it find `h3`

```
'//node/following-sibling::p[following-sibling::h3]'
```

But it does not work in case 2 where there is no `h3` but `h2`

So I am looking for a logic that keep following unless it found any other tag than `p` because it could be `h1`, `h2` `h3` etc.

So in both case i only want to select `<p>a</p>` and `<p>b</p>`

My code is running in loop so i do not have enough information about what is coming in as a sibling node.

Comment: first check what you get in `response.body` - maybe it gives you different page - ie. warning for bots :)

Comment: Your XPath work as expected unless you meant *the immediate sibling `<div>`*. In this case you can try `//div[@class='mw-parser-output']/p[not(following-sibling::*[position()=1 and name()='div'])]`

Comment: It still return all the `<p>` even a `<div>` tag is apprearing

Comment: @RaheelKhan, are you sure? I've double-checked and `p` that is immediate preceding sibling of `<div id="toc" class="toc">...</div>` was skipped. Works as expected

Comment: Just so that we are on same page, inside `mw-parser-output`  there are alot of `<p>` but there are total 7 `<p>` before the `<div id="toc">` appears. I want to target those 7 `<p>`. When i tried i got 31 `<p>`. Please let me know if you are doing same. I will try again may be i made a mistake.

Comment: So you want to get all `p` except those 7 before `<div id="toc">`, right?

Comment: @Andersson no no, Its opposite. I want those 7 `p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only first 7 `p` nodes (preceding siblings of `<div id="toc">`) you can try below XPath:

```
//div[@class='mw-parser-output']/p[following-sibling::div[@id='toc']]
```

Comment: I am sorry, i was updating the more near problem. Can you please see my question HTML. I want to select `p` before h3 tag. And it has no id

Comment: Okay I got it :) Thanks alot

Comment: Try `h3[.="Foo"]/preceding-sibling::p`

Comment: Sorry to bug again. Can we do something like.. follow `p` unless any other type of `node` appears. Because i have two conditions to follow. One is follow p until h3 appears and also follow p untill h2 appears

Comment: Sorry cant your se `h3['.=Foo]` because its dynamic and in loop. Will be very confusing.

Comment: We still talk about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping or about some other page? I need HTML sample and desired output... Can you show on example?

Comment: I drill down to the problem that is remaining based on your above answer. Please see the updated question. Thank you

Comment: You can try `//*[not(name()="p")][1]/preceding-sibling::p` or more specific `//*[name()=("h2", "h3")][1]/preceding-sibling::p`